# How to evaluate $f(x)$ at the point $(x^2 + ax + b) \in \text{Spec} \, \mathbb{R}[x] $?

Tags: polynomials, schemes, maximal-and-prime-ideals, euclidean-algorithm

Can someone help me evaluate functions $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ at the points in  $\text{Spec}\, \mathbb{R}[x]$ ?

- $(x-a) \in \text{Spec} \,\mathbb{R}[x]$ so I think we still have a point there...
- $(x^2 +ax+b) \in \text{Spec} \,\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a maximal ideal as well (if $a^2 < 4b$) and therefore also a point.

In the first case, we can value the function using the Euclidean algorithm:

$$ f(x) \equiv \;\;\;\;f(a) + (x-a)\,\mathbb{R}[x]$$

but what about the other points.  Can we evaluate $f(x)$ "at" the other maximal ideals such as $(x^2 + ax + b)$?

$$ f(x) \equiv \;? + (x^2 + ax + b)\,\mathbb{R}[x]$$

Comment: The thing you are claiming is not completely correct. It's only intuitively relaxing to think that f is a function. But essentially, value of f at a point p is: image of f in Fr(R[X]/p). Under the isomorphism R[X]/(x-a) = R, you see that image of f is f(a).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use polynomial long division to compute the remainder of $f(x)$ when dividing by $x^2+ax+b$.  The remainder will be some linear polynomial, and is a canonical representative of the residue class of $f(x)$ mod $(x^2+ax+b)$.

You can get a more concrete picture of this by identifying the residue field with $\mathbb{C}$.  Namely, if $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ is either of the two complex roots of $x^2+ax+b$, then we get an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+ax+b)\to\mathbb{C}$ sending $x$ to $\alpha$.  This isomorphism maps the residue class of $f(x)$ to $f(\alpha)$.  So, if we identify the residue field with $\mathbb{C}$, we can "evaluate" $f(x)$ at this point by just evaluating the polynomial at $x=\alpha$.